# .htaccess and CakePHP: Creating a directory for use with Angular-UI router

Tags: angularjs, apache, .htaccess, cakephp

I've got an AngularJS app running on top of CakePHP 2.6. I'd like to enable `html5mode` in Angular so I don't have to include a `#` in URLs, but doing so requires configuring some .htaccess files so that all requests hit index.html.

Not all of my web app is Angular yet, so I can't just redirect **everything** to index.html- instead, I'd like to set things up so that all requests to a certain subdirectory (and its subdirectories) redirect to that subdirectory's `index.html`.

CakePHP has a folder structure like this:

```
/                   // Server web root directory: index.php, etc
----/app            // The directory containing the actual Cake app
    ----/webroot    // Web assets used by the Cake app
        ----/myapp  // Where I'd like to store the index.html for my Angular app
```

I'd like to get this set up so that any requests to `/myapp` or its subdirectories get automatically redirected to `/app/webroot/index.html`. Does anyone have any ideas about how to go about this?

My current .htaccess files:

**/:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**/app:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

**/app/webroot:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(app/webroot/)?(img|css|js|eot)/(.*)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just create a controller in CakePHP to handle all requests for `myapp` and render the static HTML as a view with a custom layout (if required).

Performance will not be an issue because the route for CakePHP will only be executed once. After that the AngularJS app is running and will take over all HTML5 routing locally in the browser.

While you can achieve what you want in `.htaccess` it limits you to running the CakePHP application on Apache. If you want to scale later to IIS or Nginx you'll have to recreate these rewrite rules.